# jquery Object has no method 'xyz'

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
var $content    = $('#SomeDivContainingTwoImages');
$content.children().each(function(i){
    $(this).showImage = showImageStatic;
    $(this).showImage();
});
```

returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'showImage'
```

when run. This works outside of the jquery each iterator, ie if I just apply it to a single element. What's up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are re-creating a jQuery object with every call to $(this).

This should work:

```
$content.children().each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.showImage = showImageStatic;
    $this.showImage();
});
```

But I think that's not a very good way of handling it. You could call showImageStatic() directly:

```
showImageStatic.call($(this));
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` creates a new instance every time.
The second `$(this)` doesn't have the method you added to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the right way to add a function, you should do

```
$.fn.extend({ "showImage" : showImageStatic });
```

and it should allow you to call showImage() properly.

Comment: would that add it to all jquery objects?

Comment: This would add the function to all jQuery objects